# Avoid foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have hierarchy level tables 1 through 7 and Each table has foreign key with a column from next level table.

My task is to insert hierarchy level data in those tables.

As there are foreign key constraints , i need to insert data in reverse order like l7 first, then l6,l5,....till l1.

Buy in one situation, I have data for only l3,l2,l1..

Now problem is - for inserting l3 I don't have data for l4.

so I am getting constraint error.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I avoid this error.

Comment: Pl. post in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

It's a session-based statement.

This is to temporarily break the Foreign Key Constraint. It is sometimes necessary to change data in a way that referential integrity needs to be broken during the modification process.

For More Detail
http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/set_foreign_key_checks

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood properly you have relations now as per your example, I3 have a column which is referring towards I4 that column is a foreign key. Now if you do not have the foreign key value while inserting I3 you can insert null in that foreign key column.

Not very sure if its answer your question.